# MSSQL Dynamic for loop

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

First of all, I am by no means an SQL guru, although I dabble...

My problem is as follows; I have a large database containing a table for

- iteminfo (basic item descriptions) (.[itemno])
- solditems (information on an item's sale) (.[itemno] .[ratecode] .[qty] .[price])
- rates (basically the sale price for the items) (.[ratecode])

I need to generate a report (crystal reports) that shows for each item how many times it's been sold under each rate and the total value for that. Problem I run into is that the [rates] table might be a different size for different databases, and more rates can get added or unused rates get removed.

I've built the following SQL query that gets this info out, but if there are 10 different rates in the database I need to copy-past the code below 10 times making the query very messy, and of course it doesn't take into account an 11th rate, and starts returning odd values if a rate is removed (or worse, if rate nr 5 gets removed and the 6 becomes 5, 7 becomes 6, etc).

Note: s.itemno refers to the main query and is the itemnumber for the specific item being queried.

```
(select count(solditems.ratecode) 
 from solditems 
 where solditems.itemno = s.itemno 
   and solditems.ratecode = (
       select [ratecode] 
       from (
          select row_number() over (order by [ratecode]) as  rownumber, * 
          from dbo.rates
       ) as mytable 
       where rownumber = '**1**'
  )
) as ratqty**1**,


(select sum(solditems.qty * solditems.price) from solditems 
where solditems.itemno = s.itemno and solditems.ratecode = (select 
    [ratecode] from (select row_number() over (order by [ratecode]) as 
    rownumber, * from dbo.rates) as mytable where rownumber = '**1**')) 
as rateval**1**,
...
```

Were I using a programming language like C I'd just write a for loop like (Pseudocode): int maxi = count(rates.ratecode) for i = 0 and i!=maxi {do stuff for rownumber i} i++.

Q1: Is there a way to build a for loop like that in SQL (has to be compatible with crystal reports, so the simpler the better).

Q2: How would I go about avoiding issues if a rate is removed and the subsequent tables move up a spot (6 becomes 5, 7 becomes 6, etc).

Bonus Q: Above code is not very elegant, is there a simpler way?

Requested sample output:

itemno 1 has been sold 5 times for €1000 each under ratecode 1, 1 times for €100 under ratecode 2
itemno 2 has been sold 6 times for €500 each under ratecode 1, 
etc.

[sampleoutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qli0V.png)

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output

Comment: What do you change in this code when you copy it for another "rate"? Filtering value for `rownumber`?

Comment: This sounds like something `GROUP BY` could potentially solve, but it's hard to tell without data. Can you post some example data and expected output?

Comment: Added to original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid loops and copy-pasting you'll need a `dynamic pivot` for two aggregated values like that:

```
DECLARE
  @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'',
  @qty_cols NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'',
  @val_cols NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'',
  @n int = 0

    -- this can be done in any other manner like via spt_values or FOR XML and so on
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
      @n += 1,
      @qty_cols += ', [rateqty-' + CAST(@n AS VARCHAR(10)) + ']',
      @val_cols += ', [rateval-' + CAST(@n AS VARCHAR(10)) + ']',
      @cmd += ', MAX([rateqty-' + CAST(@n AS VARCHAR(10)) + ']) as [rateqty-' + CAST(@n AS VARCHAR(10)) + ']'
       + ', MAX([rateval-' + CAST(@n AS VARCHAR(10)) + ']) as [rateval-' + CAST(@n AS VARCHAR(10)) + ']'
    FROM #rates r
    ORDER BY r.ratecode

set @cmd = 'SELECT ' + STUFF(@cmd, 1, 2, '') + '
  from 
  (
    select 
      ''rateqty-'' + CAST(rn AS VARCHAR(10)) ratecode_qty, 
      ''rateval-'' + CAST(rn AS VARCHAR(10)) ratecode_val, 
      rateqty, rateval
    from (
      select ratecode, rateqty, rateval, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY r.ratecode) rn
      from #rates r
    ) r
  ) r
  pivot (max(r.rateqty) for ratecode_qty in (' + STUFF(@qty_cols, 1, 2, '') + ' )) p1
  pivot (max(p1.rateval) for ratecode_val in (' + STUFF(@val_cols, 1, 2, '') + ' )) p2
  order by 1'

exec(@cmd)
;
```

For these sample data:

```
insert into rates(ratecode)
values (1), (2), (3)

insert into solditems(ratecode, qty, price)
values
 (1, 5, 22),
 (1, 2, 22),
 (3, 1, 33)
```

output will be:

```
| rateqty-1 | rateval-1 | rateqty-2 | rateval-2 | rateqty-3 | rateval-3 |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|         2 |       154 |         0 |         0 |         1 |        33 |
```

Full source here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6f390/42

As of the question about simplifying your subqueries in the report where more source tables partake then my guess (since you've shown only part of code) is `ratecodes` have to be `CROSS JOIN`ed to the outer query (which sounds a bit scary), or joined to `solditems` directly and aggregated (*and then* pivoted) like that:

```
SELECT 
  ...
FROM ... <outer query>
CROSS APPLY
(
  select
     r.ratecode,
     count(1) rateqty,  -- i don't quite understand what is this supposed to be; number of transactions?
     sum(si.qty * si.price) rateval
  from solditems si
  INNER JOIN dbo.rates r
   ON si.ratecode = r.ratecode
  where si.itemno = s.itemno
  group by r.ratecode
) s
```

upd: after posting this subquery I realized that `dbo.rates` is used nowhere except `ROWNUMBER`. So if you do pivoting, no join to `rates` required here:

```
SELECT 
  ...
FROM ... <outer query>
CROSS APPLY
(
  select
     si.ratecode,
     count(1) rateqty,
     sum(si.qty * si.price) rateval
  from solditems si
  where si.itemno = s.itemno
  group by si.ratecode
) s
```

Comment: This is brilliant. It'll take me a bit to figure out how it works so that I can implement it, but it gives me exactly what I want. Thank you!